# What is the third derivative of $\prod _{i=0}^n\:\left(x-x_i\right)$?

Tags: derivatives, products

$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\prod \:_{i=0}^n\:\left(x-x_i\right)\right)$$

How can I calculate this? $x_i$ are numbers, not variables, the only variable here is x

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, but I thought that if we'd know n then we could just calculate it from scratch, it'd be long but ok. But here, we do not know n, so I am asking if there is a general formula if I want to derive such products

Comment: Google "Liebniz Formula"

Comment: @anon Working with $n$ is not very different... You will just need to use more compact notations to feel the problem instead of writing down every term individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)\right)'=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{i=1,\\i\ne j}^n(x-x_i)$$

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)\right)''=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=1,\\i\ne j\\i\ne k}^n(x-x_i)$$

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)\right)'''=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n\prod_{i=1,\\i\ne j\\i\ne k\\i\ne l}^n(x-x_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Take $$y=\left(\prod \:_{i=0}^n\:\left(x-x_i\right)\right)$$
then
$$\ln y=\sum_{i=0}^n \ln(x-x_i)$$
and
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{x-x_i}$$
this makes it easy for another derivative.

Comment: How would you address the second derivative ?